# How to exchange a seat stray on a 2013 Cube AMS 150 Super HPC Race carbon bike?

Tags: mountain-bike, frames, carbon

The derailleur was torn apart so I ordered new seat stays and have to exchange (one of them).

I'm not sure how to do it, there are some bearings fastened by screws where hex-wrenches seem to fit on both sides but I am a bit afraid to use brute force and possibly break something.

This is what it looks like:
https://goo.gl/photos/Cq8kWhYF8ES3ouBEA

Shall I just try to unscrew that pulling the hex wrenches into opposite directions or I need some special tools?

Comment: I would expect the manufacturer will supply instructions, which will include torque values for fasteners.

Comment: in fact I can unscrew the "inner" screws but the outer ones just turn around, so I cannot take out the seat stay out of the frame yet... The only thing I get from their instruction is that the torque value is 8Nm or something.

Comment: Carbon is very easy to damage. Maybe have a professional handle the repair if you're not sure how to do it.

Comment: done! however.. the seat strays they sent me are too short. hooray bloody hell!!!

Answer (score 1):

I basically did it myself, i needed neither any special tools nor brute force.

Comment: I hope you used the correct threadlocker on those bolts!